# strange behavior of ERRORLEVEL between XP and WIN10

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

i've this simple batch file

```
@SET SIMPLE=
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 @ECHO error found
```

the problem is when I run this .bat file in :

Windows XP: it prints error found
Windows 10: it prints nothing (ERRORLEVEL 0)

for sure there is a difference between CMD.exe of OS xp & Win 10 but not for such things no ?

Comment: What is the purpose of chacking the errorlevel following that command, off the top of my head, I cannot envisage a reason for doing so. Apart from that, I'd use `@(SET SIMPLE=)`, or `@SET "SIMPLE="`.

Comment: @Compo, in  XP always the errorlevel is one using `@(SET SIMPLE=)` or `@SET "SIMPLE="` in Win10 the errorlevel stay 0 using the same commands !

Comment: Agnes, can you please confirm that both your batch files are using the correct `.CMD` extension, and not the superseded `.BAT` one. If not please do that first, and try again. Could you also try it by preceding those two lines with this one `@SORT 0< NUL 1> NUL`.

Comment: up to a certain version of xp, the `set` command itself sets an `errorlevel`, after that, the `set` command no longer sets `errorlevel` as the command never fails. `set var=` is effectively a valid command and will set `errorlevel` of `0`. Keep in mind `if errorlevel 1` actually matches `if errorlevel >= 1` and `0` being les than 1, it will jot.match. i cannot remember what version of windows xp it changed though.

Comment: That being said, are you just looking for the reason this happens, or are you looking to see if the variable has an actual value? If the latter, then `if not defined simple echo Variable not defined`

Comment: BTW, Windows XP reached End Of Life on 2014-04-08, just over six (6) years ago. But, who's counting. :-)